# First UICollectionViewCell doesn't update with firebase data on swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

When I go into the view with the collectionView my first cell have the same data of the second cell, but if i go back to the homeView and return into the collectionView it have the right data inside

I have this code for load posts from Firebase

```
func loadPosts(){
    Toast(text:"User profile loaded").show()
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let displayName = currentUser?.displayName
    dbRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: displayName).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var newUtente = [MyStruct]()
        for snapshotValue in snapshot.children.allObjects {
            let restObject = MyStruct(snapshot: snapshotValue as! DataSnapshot)
            newUtente.append(restObject)
        }
        self.Utente = newUtente
        self.Utente = self.Utente.sorted(by: { $0.trimtime?.compare($1.trimtime! as String) == .orderedDescending })
        //print(self.Utente)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
           self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()

    })
}
```

[image: CollectionView with same data of the second cell]

In the code of the Cell i have this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cella = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: "cella", for: indexPath) as! ChatViewCell

        if (indexPath.row == 0){
            collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
            cella.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor("#DAE3FB").cgColor
            let user = user2[indexPath.row]
            cella.Label1?.text = user.username
            key = user.key
            last = user.lastname
        } else if (indexPath.row >= 1){
            let user = Utente[indexPath.row]
            cella.LabelEur.text = user.price+"€"
            test19 = user.price
            cella.LabelR.text = user.sender
            cella.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor("#FFFFFF").cgColor
            if (user.positionDef != nil) {
                if (user.positionDef.hasPrefix("0")) {
                    cella.Distanza.text = "Nelle vicinanze"
                } else {
                    cella.Distanza.text = user.positionDef+"KM"
                }
            }
            cella.City?.text = user.city
            self.Utente = self.Utente.sorted{ $0.price.compare($1.price, options: .numeric) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }

        }
        return cella
    }
```

I have no idea why it happens.
After the back and the return between homeView and CollectionView

[image: Data refreshed]

Anyone have some idea?

Comment: The method `cellForItemAt` is called for every cell, and cells are dequeued so in the function after dequeuing the cell, reset all the labels / fields in the cell. It is possible that the old value is being shown.

Comment: @user1046037 so first to call "if (ndexPath.row == 0)" i need to set all label nil?

Comment: No, after dequeueing the cell just set all labels text = ""

Comment: Nothing, the first cell as the same to the second